OutputCache Read Response Body in ServeResponseAsync(..) in custom policy so that I can use this information to build tags
I want to add tags to the OutputCacheContext.Tags in the ServeResponseAsync(..). This is because I want to evict caches based on information found in the response
Microsoft does not provide a public API to do this so I used reflection to access the OutputCacheStream in both the context.HttpContext.Request.Body (which is a OutputCacheStream boxed as a Stream) and the internal OutputCacheContext.OutputCacheStream like this:
var outputCacheStream = typeof(OutputCacheContext)
    .GetProperty("OutputCacheStream", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)?
    .GetValue(context);

var stream = outputCacheStream
    .GetType()
    .GetMethod("GetCachedResponseBody", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)?
    .Invoke(outputCacheStream, null);

var sequence = (ReadOnlySequence<byte>)stream;

// now I can inspect this to add tags
string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sequence.First.Span);

This works fine, but the problem is that the GetCachedResponseBody() calls _segmentWriteStream.DetachAndReset() which ultimately causes the OutputCacheMiddleware to serve null when the cache is requested and returned on subsequent requests.
Does anyone know how to get the response body as a string without breaking the OutputCache?
